# Simple TCP socket and HTTP proxy on single port with nginx

Tags: sockets, http, nginx, tcp, proxy

I have a process listening to port `23333` and I also have some files I would like to serve through HTTPS in a directory on my server, say `/var/www/files/`

Can I use `nginx` to serve files and act as a proxy to the socket on a single port, e.g. `21000`?

E.g. be able to do:

`telnet example.com 21000`

and

`curl https://example.com:21000/files/file.txt`

Comment: Your question is ambiguous. When you say "use `nginx` to serve both files and socket", do you mean to use `nginx` to serve files and also have a socket? Or do you mean to use `nginx` both to serve files and to have a socket?

Comment: Sorry about that. Is this more clear? 'Can I use nginx to serve files and act as a proxy to the socket on a single port, e.g. 21000?'

Comment: The easiest way to do this would probably be to put the support in the process. When you start reading data on the connection, check if the data appears to be an HTTP request (Starts with `GET`, `PUT`, `POST`, `HEAD`, or `CONNECT`). If so, proxy between the remote connection and nginx.

Comment: Well, I'm hoping to get nginx to that for me. I recently managed to make it listen for http requests as well as websocket connections on the same port, so I'm looking for something similar. Here's what I used for that: http://nginx.com/blog/websocket-nginx/